# jQuery Wrap Elements Created By .Each Method in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, dom

I want to wrap elements created from a the `.each` method in a `div`.

Here's my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "xml/timeline.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXML
    });

    function parseXML(xml) {

      $(xml).find("Year").each(function() {
        var year = $(this).attr("year");
        $(".timeLineWrapper").append('<h2 class="timeYearHead">' + year + "</h2>");
        $(this).find("Event").each(function() {
          var event = $(this).text();
          $(".timeLineWrapper").append('<p>' + event + '</p>');
        }); // close find Event
      }); // close find Year
    } // close parseXML   
  }); // Close docDotReady
</script>
```

The basic idea is to create a heading for each year and underneath that list the events for each year, of which there will be varying numbers. I want to wrap the events in a `div` after they've been parsed from the XML file. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but could you post a snippet of the `html` that results from this ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xml/timeline.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });

        function parseXML(xml){

            $(xml).find("Year").each(function(){
                var year = $(this).attr("year");            
                $(".timeLine").append('&lt;li class="timeYear"&gt;&lt;h2 class="timeYearHead"&gt;' + year + "&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/li&gt;");   
                $(this).find("Event").each(function(){  
                    var event = $(this).text();             
                    $(".timeLine").append('&lt;li class="timeEvent"&gt;' + event + '&lt;/li&gt;');
                }); // close find Event
            }); // close find Year
        } // close parseXML   
    }); // Close docDotReady

    </script>
```

Here's the HTML output it produces:

```
<ul class="timeLine">
    <li class="timeYear">
        <h2 class="timeYearHead">1950</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        One
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Two
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Three
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Four
    </li>
    <li class="timeYear">
        <h2 class="timeYearHead">1951</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Five
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Six
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Seven
    </li>
    <li class="timeYear">
        <h2 class="timeYearHead">1952</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Eight
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Nine
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Ten
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Eleven
    </li>
    <li class="timeEvent">
        Twelve
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, I am trying to parse this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Years>
    <Year year="1950">
        <Events>
            <Event>
                One
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Two
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Three
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Four
            </Event>
        </Events>
    </Year>
    <Year year="1951">
        <Events>
            <Event>
                Five
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Six
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Seven
            </Event>
        </Events>
    </Year>
    <Year year="1952">
        <Events>
            <Event>
                Eight
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Nine
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Ten
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Eleven
            </Event>
            <Event>
                Twelve
            </Event>
        </Events>
    </Year>
</Years>
```

My goal is to create a  with a  on it for each year in the XML file with a sub-list  for each list of events corresponding with that year and a  for each event on that list.

Comment: if this is information regarding the question, you should move it to the 'question' section, not as an 'answer'.